# Input String through 2-D array

Tags: arrays, c

I have seen other similar question but none of them solved my problem.

```
char name[30][15];
  
int i, n, found=0;
printf("Enter how many names you want to enter:");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Enter names of %d friends:", n);
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  scanf("%s", name[i]);
    printf("Names are: ");
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  printf("%s\n", name[i]);
```

If I run this code, its runs properly but how can we input 1-D array when the array we defined is 2-D. Is the no of columns defined by default if we use `name[i]`.
if I modify this code, it shows error.--

```
char name[30][15];
   
    int i, n, found=0;
    printf("Enter how many names you want to enter:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter names of %d friends:", n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
      scanf("%s", name[i][15]);
        printf("Names are: ");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
      printf("%s\n", name[i]);
```

The output is--

```
Enter how many names you want to enter:2                                                                                                      
Enter names of 2 friends:vyom                                                                                                                 
Names are:
```

Comment: BTW, please add braces to ALL `for` loops. It makes the code easy to read and less bug-prone. And keep indentation *consistent* - it doesn't make sense to further nest `printf` at all given that it should probably be at the outermost indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf("%s", name[i][15]);` is different compared to `scanf("%s", name[i]);`

type of `name[i][15]` is `char` and type of `name[i]` is `char*`

`scanf` expects `char*` when reading strings, that is the  reason in the second case its not behaving as you expected.

Use `scanf("%s", name[i]);` for reading strings, better yet use [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read multi word strings.

Comment: so I defined it as `char name[30][15];`, then I can change to to `char*` right?

Comment: can you explain what is happening, I used a char array `char name[30][15];`, then I used `name[i]` to read input for the 2-D array, please just a little detail.

Comment: `char name[30][15]` means `name` is an array of characters in which you can store 30 strings each with length of 15 including `\0`,the each string is accessed using `name [ i ]` where i ranges from 0 - 29 and `name [ i ][ j ]` refers to  a jth character in ith string, so `name[i]` refers to the address of ith string , so it works when used in `scanf`. if this is still not clear, please open a new post asking for any doubts,